# Java Parallel search in a multidimensional array using Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, search, java-threads

The task is to find max and min values in a **MxN matrix**, and do it "***in parallel***" using Java Threads.

I was pretty surprised to find out that my `parallelSearch()` method runs much slower compared to the `regularSearch()` method. Both of them use the same brute-force algorithm, so even though you can probably solve this problem using a better **algorithm**, both methods should be on the even playing field.

I'm curious to find out why: is it because creating new Thread objects is a time-expensive task, or is it because I'm doing something totally wrong in my `parallelSearch()` method?

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Task {
    static int max = -1;
    static int min = 99;
    static int[][] matrix;
    static Random rnd = new Random();
    static{
        matrix = new int[4][1000];
        Task t = new Task();
        t.fill(matrix);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Task t = new Task();
        long cur = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(t.regularSearch(matrix));
        System.out.println("regular search took "+(System.currentTimeMillis() - cur)+" millis ");
        cur = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(t.parallelSearch(matrix));
        System.out.println("parallel search took "+(System.currentTimeMillis() - cur)+" millis ");

    }
    void fill(int[][] input){
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            for (int i1 = 0; i1 < input[i].length; i1++) {
                input[i][i1] = rnd.nextInt(200);
            }
        }
    }
    String regularSearch(int[][]input){
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (int[] anInput : input) {
            for (int anAnInput : anInput) {
                if(anAnInput>max){
                    max = anAnInput;
                }
                if(anAnInput<min){
                    min = anAnInput;
                }
            }
        }
        String rslt = result.append("max: ").append(max).append(" min: ").append(min).toString();
        max = -1;
        min = 200; //doing this to have a fair comparison in main()
        return rslt;
    }
    String parallelSearch(int[][] input) throws InterruptedException {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < input[0].length; i++) {
            int x = i;
            Thread t = new Thread(()->{
                for (int[] anInput : input) {
                    if (anInput[x] > max) {
                        max = anInput[x];
                    }
                    if (anInput[x] < min) {
                        min = anInput[x];
                    }
                }
            });
            t.start();
        }
        Thread.sleep(10);
        result.append("max: ").append(max).append(" min: ").append(min);
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

EDIT:
As was pointed out in the comments, my `parallelSearch()` was creating way more Threads than necessary, and I've rewritten it to better suit my task. This one actually runs faster than the regular one on big sizes. I've tested it against a 4x500000 matrix with `random.nextInt(100000)` bound and it runs as fast or even up to 10 seconds faster then the `regularSearch()`

```
String parallelSearch(int[][] input) throws InterruptedException {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            int x = i;
            Thread t = new Thread(()->{
                for(int num:input[x]){
                    if(num>max){
                        max = num;
                    }
                    if(num<min){
                        min = num;
                    }
                }
            });
            t.start();
        }
        Thread.sleep(10);
        result.append("max: ").append(max).append(" min: ").append(min);
        return result.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Multi-threaded programming is hard in many ways. For example here your 4*1000 array is so small that it's unlikely that the additional threads can offset the cost of their creation and other things, resulting in a slower total performance. It's like doing your dishes, which is faster: doing them yourself or waiting for your 3 friends to come over and help?

Comment: Regular search does `for (int[] anInput : input)` (`4` iterations) while parallel search does `for (int i = 0; i < input[0].length; i++)` (`1000` threads). So you are actually doing searching `1000` times in the parallel version.

Comment: Are you creating ONE thread per item in your matrix? I suppose this is OK for matrices with 4 items, but imagine a matrix in the hundreds. Not an expert in multithreading programming, but I'm sure it's not right.

Comment: You're trying something hard here. Your multithread implementation is broken because of race conditions between reads and writes on the `max` and `min` static variables. Rule of thumb : never share data (variable read/write) accross threads without having a "synchronization" mechanism of some sort. Here, a possible way to achieve that would be for each thread to have its *own* `min`and `max`, and for the main thread to merge each threads result. (There are other possibilities, countless even, but that's a simple one).